# Method to determine an order of an arbitrary permutation matrix

Tags: group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

This may seem like a commonly asked question (e.g. [another post with basically the same title](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189823/determining-the-power-of-permutation-matrix-of-order-n-times-n-to-get-identity)), but I am interested in a method of finding an order of an arbitrary permutation matrix, assuming that sometimes the matrix is so large that it is impractical to inspect the lengths manually.

This will be, for example, useful for writing a computer programming function that takes in any permutation matrix P and spits out the order of P (namely, $\min_n P^n=I$).

One method is a brute-force approach, where we keep increase $n$ until we get $P^n=I$. However, I am wondering if there is a cleverer method.

Comment: Your method allows you to find the order of the permutation, but then how do you get the length of each cycle?

Comment: @Yorch, sorry I confused 'length' and 'order'. I edited the title and the post. I am interested in finding the order of the permutation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can do it, assume the matrix is $n\times n$.

Obtain the permutation $f:\{1,\dots, n\} \rightarrow \{1,\dots, n\}$ where $f(j)$ is equal to the row $x$ such that $A_{x,j} = 1$.

Decompose permutation $f$ into cycles by doing a search over the digraph with vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$ and edges $i\rightarrow f(i)$.

The order of the matrix is equal to the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of all the cycle lengths.

[Some c++ code:](https://jorgeferh.xyz/code/orderperm.txt)

Comment: This should run in $O(n^2)$ time, right? Since obtaining the permutation $f$ is $O(n^2)$ and the actual decomposition into cycles is $O(n)$? Just wanna make sure I understand this algorithm properly.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example code! So this method finds the lengths of all cycles as well which can be useful for many applications, although it may not be faster than the brute-force method mentioned in the post (which does not identify all cycles).

Comment: The brute force method is ridiculously slower than this method, even for matrices of order 2.

Comment: Yeah it takes $\mathcal O(n^2)$ because we have to read the matrix but after we get $f$ it's $\mathcal O(n)$.

Comment: @CWC To show that brute force is indeed slower, consider that you essentially have to implement matrix multiplication (although you can make a lot of simplifications, knowing the structure of the matrices) to do this, and try to consider the worst-case-complexity of this kind of repeated multiplication

Comment: @tolUene I see. I failed to consider the complexity of matrix multiplications. Thank you!

Comment: It now works on all permutations of degree up to 6. I was going to mention, an input like `10 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0` requires 30 matrix multiplies (so around 30,000 operations) in the brute force method, but more like 100 memory accesses and just a few multiplies and remainders in your method.