# Solve $P^n=I$ for smallest $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I would like to solve $P^n=I$ for smallest $n$, where $P$ is a matrix and $n$ is a positive integer. $P$ is a permutation matrix. Is there an expansion that approximates $n$?

I have a similar question posted here ([Method to determine an order of an arbitrary permutation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197829/method-to-determine-an-order-of-an-arbitrary-permutation-matrix)) with a great answer by @Asinomas, but this time, I am looking for a purely linear algebraic approach. I assume that some kind of approximation by expansion would be needed.

Comment: This is not clear. What conditions do you have on $P$ ? The integer $n$ may not exist.

Comment: Good point. I will constrain the $P$ to be a permutation matrix.

Comment: Well, if $P$ is a permutation matrix, then the integer $n$ you are looking at is just the order of the permutation associated to the matrix. It can be expressed as the lcm of all the lengths of the cycles that compose your permutation.

Comment: Edited the post to make my question more specific. Thank you though!